# Can I power 25 LED via USB?

Tags: arduino-nano, power, led

So I'm currently working on a project where I build a WordClock. To display the current time I use WS2812B LEDs which should be white when turned on. Only about 25 leds per time will be turned on, the rest will be off. If my calculation is correct that should result in 1,5A (25leds x 60ma = 1500ma = 1,5A). 
With the little power consumption of the Arduino Nano I think it won't exceed 2 amps at a time. 
Is it safe to power this from a standard USB port or do I need some of the relatively overpriced (at least here in Germany) led power supply? What's the worst that could happen if I would exceed the amperage of the power supply? Would the LEDs just be dimmed or would it be dangerous in any way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. 25 LEDs on full white will draw 1.5A.

You cannot drive this from a standard USB port on your PC. These ports can give up to 500mA (higher currents for USB3.0 ports will only be available after additional negatiations - not possible with a Nano). When powering from such a port, the port will either go into emergency shutdown (reenabling after the next reboot), or you will damage the USB port beyond repair.

But you don't need an overpriced power supply, that is meant for these LEDs. The WS2812B LEDs work on 5V, so you can use any 5V DC wallwart power supply, for example a standard USB charger, that gives you at least 2A.

> What's the worst that could happen if I would exceed the amperage of the power supply?

In general you risk to damage the power supply, so that it won't work anymore. Drawing more power than allowed from a power supply is like a short, which is never good. Also too hot wires and such can cause fires.

But that is not always true. I tested a big strip of those LEDs on a simple USB charger myself one time. The charger was not rated high enough for all the LEDs. So the LEDs lit up for a very short time (like a flash) again and again with about 1s between each flash, as the USB charger tried to supply the voltage and did go into emergency shutdown again. This didn't hurt the USB charger, though I would not do this for very long. Also you cannot be sure, that your USB charger will do the same. (I also live in germany, so it might be the same case). Also look at the description of the chargers. Sometimes they write a high current into the title of multiple port chargers, but this current is distributed between the ports, so that you need multiple cables to draw the full current.

As USB chargers are quite cheap, I would suggest to use one of these. Pay extra attention to the current rating and stay well above your requirements (2A should be enough).

**Very important:** Be sure, that you don't draw the LEDs current through the Arduino. This would fry it's protection diode. Instead connect the LEDs power lines directly to the power supply, in parallel to the Arduino.

Comment: @Janik, you might want to check out any old phone (tablet etc) chargers that you have laying around.  The first two that I pulled out of my box delivered 2A@5V (Samsung) and 2.1A@5.1V (Apple) - and to all the "I don't like what you said - so I will down vote you people" on this site, this is the rating that is written on the charger.

Comment: Actually found a 3a@5v fast charger in my drawer, gonna use this, thanks

Comment: Cool. Just remember what chrisl said about *not* drawing the power through the arduino (last paragraph in the answer)